# Html2Canvas: Inconsistent PDF Image Output Across Devices

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, html2canvas

Issue Summary:

I am encountering discrepancies in the PDF images generated using Html2Canvas across different devices. While the design appears satisfactory on my laptop, it exhibits variations on other devices such as phones or different laptops. I suspect this inconsistency may stem from differences in screen resolution.

Code Snippet:

```
const DownloadBarcodes = async () => {
try {
  const { isConfirmed } = await getBarcodeText();

  if (isConfirmed) {
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      unit: "mm",
      format: "a4",
    });

    const imgWidth = 210;
    const imgHeight = 296;
    const qrCodeContainer = document.createElement("div");
    qrCodeContainer.style.width = `${imgWidth}mm`;
    qrCodeContainer.style.height = `${imgHeight}mm`;
    document.body.appendChild(qrCodeContainer);

    const root = createRoot(qrCodeContainer);
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      const headerText = j === 0 ? "Good morning !" : "Good evening ! ";
      for (let i = 0; i < qrCodes.length + 1; i++) {
        const firstName = await extractNameWithoutNumber(
          qrCodes[i]?.waiterName.split(" ")[0]
        );
        root.render(
          <BarcodePaperTemplate
            url={qrCodes[i]?.url}
            name={firstName}
            headerText={headerText}
          />
        );

        const canvas = await html2canvas(qrCodeContainer, {
          willReadFrequently: true,
        });
        const qrCodeDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        if (i > 0) {
          pdf.addImage(qrCodeDataUrl, "PNG", 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          if (i < qrCodes.length + 1) {
            pdf.addPage();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // Remove the last page (empty page)
    pdf.deletePage(pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
    document.body.removeChild(qrCodeContainer);
    const fileName = `${hallChoosen.hallName}.pdf`;
    pdf.save(fileName);

    handleClose();
  }
} catch (e) {
  handleClose();
} finally {
  ShowDialogAgain();
}};
```

Issue Details:

Platform Differences: The PDF output from Html2Canvas varies notably across devices, indicating potential discrepancies in rendering due to screen resolution or other device-specific factors.
Consistency Concerns: While the design appears satisfactory on the developer's laptop, it exhibits unexpected scale styles and variations on other devices such as phones or different laptops.
Probable Cause: The root cause of this inconsistency is likely associated with differences in screen resolution or rendering mechanisms between various devices.

What I Tried:
I attempted to generate PDF images using Html2Canvas within a React application. The code snippet provided utilizes Html2Canvas to convert the content of a div into a base64 string and then captures the element to a PDF file. I ensured that the PDF format was set to A4 size, and I handled the image dimensions appropriately.

Expectations:
I expected the generated PDF images to exhibit consistent designs across different devices. Specifically, I anticipated that the layout and scale styles would remain uniform regardless of the device used for rendering. On my laptop, the design appeared satisfactory, leading me to believe that the code implementation was correct.

Actual Results:
However, when testing the application on various devices such as phones or other laptops, I observed significant variations in the PDF output. The scale styles differed, and the layout was inconsistent compared to the results obtained on my laptop. This inconsistency suggests that the PDF images generated on different devices are not aligned, potentially due to differences in screen resolutions or other device-specific factors.

Request for Assistance:
I am seeking guidance on how to ensure consistent PDF output across different devices when utilizing Html2Canvas for conversion. Any insights or recommendations to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: do not post code as an image

Comment: Hey buddy, thank you for your feedback. I apologize for the oversight. I have now updated the post to ensure that the code is provided as text instead of an image.

Comment: If you need the output to be absolutely the same on all platforms, don't use `html2canvas` to create your PDFs, use something like https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF.

Comment: hey @AKX , im using jspdf , but i need to cupture the element that im creating in each paper 
<BarcodePaperTemplate />

Comment: Do you need to use a React component template? You'd probably get a better result by just laying out text and images using jsPDF by hand. https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html

Comment: the BarcodePaperTemplate is a complex template that is more readable using components and created in a complex way, which means that I rather use the BarcodePaperTemplate than create it directly to jspdf without using html2canvas , why is the html2canvas made for if not for this type of reasons?

Comment: In fairness, html2canvas's readme says "The script is still in a very experimental state" and that it might not be perfect. Its license also says there are no warranties whatsoever for its use – you're free to write a better one.